# Complex search in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to make a complex search in the MySQL database. I would like to solve it with a query to avoid most of the changes in PHP code.

This is how it should work:

1. User enters text in the search field
2. System searches in keywords
3. System searches in names
4. System searches in text
5. System searches in categories.

If the system finds a match in the keywords: 1 point, if it is also in the name: 1 point, if it is also in the text: 1 point/mention, if it is also in category: 1 point.

The user with the most points is first place, the user with the second most points is in second place, and so on

Is this query doable using IF, ELSE, CASE, WHEN? I've never done this kind of a complex search. Problem to be bigger, I'm looking at two tables:

```
TABLE USERS:
id    |    name    |    lastname    |    category    |    keywords    |    text    |
TABLE PAGES:
id    |    user_id    |
```

I need to list table "users" but IF user have own pages to first display users who have "pages" and after that to list others who don't have "pages".

Comment: Have you investigated the FULLTEXT search feature set in MySQL? It may yield the sort of results you need.

Comment: It almostly certainly is possible, because subqueries essentially mean you can generate virtual temporary tables, so you can slowly build the result However, it might not be particularly efficient. Why the need to avoid PHP to process results?

Comment: A union query, perhaps? `select 1 as points, 'names' as source ... union all select 2 as points, 'keywords' as source ... etc...`?

Comment: I'm investigated the FULLTEXT in database. I do not want to have lots of sql query and in php works "if"/"else" switching and counting. Current search page is big and I need to changed everything. The only solution is to replace only a query and input function in PHP for generating words and string cleaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `order by`.  Here is an example using `like`, just for the search term:

```
select u.*
from users u
order by ((keywords like '%@SEARCHTERM%') +
          (name like '%@SEARCHTERM%') +
          (text like '%@SEARCHTERM%') +
          (category like '%@SEARCHTERM%')
         ) desc;
```

To get information about pages, join that in:

```
select u.*
from users u left outer join
     (select user_id, count(*) as numpages
      from pages p
      group by user_id
     ) p
     on u.id = p.user_id
order by (p.numages > 0) desc,
         ((keywords like '%@SEARCHTERM%') +
          (name like '%@SEARCHTERM%') +
          (text like '%@SEARCHTERM%') +
          (category like '%@SEARCHTERM%')
         ) desc;
```

The conditions in the `order by` use the fact that MySQL treats boolean values like numbers, with `1` for true and `0` for false.  You can add them up to get total of the matches.

This example uses `like`.  You can do something similar with `match . . . against` if you prefer full text search.

EDIT:

If you are concerned that the columns might contain `NULL`, then use `coalesce()`:

```
order by (p.numages > 0) desc,
         ((coalesce(keywords, '') like '%@SEARCHTERM%') +
          (coalesce(name, '') like '%@SEARCHTERM%') +
          (coalesce(text, '') like '%@SEARCHTERM%') +
          (coalesce(category, '') like '%@SEARCHTERM%')
         ) desc;
```

Comment: Note: This is good, if we have a guarantee that the columns being "searched" (with the LIKE operator) are NOT NULL. In the more general case, we would want to anticipate how `NULL` values will impact the "points" expression. To appropriatley handle NULL values, we could do something along the lines of **`IFNULL(category,'') LIKE '%t%'`** or **`IF(category LIKE '%t%',1,0)`**

Comment: @spencer7593 . . . That is a good point.  I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

I take the specification provided to mean that if a match is not found in `keyword` column, points is 0. If match is found in `keyword` but not in `name` column, points is 1. If match is found in both `keyword` and `name` column, but not in `text` column, score is 2. etc.  (I may have misunderstood the specification, attributing more meaning to the order the matches were listed, and the "if it is **also** in"... if a match is found in `name`, but not in `keywords`, then we wouldn't say "it **also** matches name".)

One alternative, using MySQL `IF()` function.

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
     , t.lastname
     , t.category
     , t.keywords
     , t.text
     , IF(t.keywords LIKE '%text%'
         ,IF(t.name LIKE '%text%'
            ,IF(t.text LIKE '%text%'
               ,IF(t.category LIKE '%text%'
                  ,4
                  ,3)
               ,2)
            ,1)
         ,0) AS `points`
  FROM `users` t
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT p.user_id FROM pages p GROUP BY p.user_id ) q
    ON q.user_id = t.id
HAVING `points` > 0
 ORDER
    BY `points` DESC, q.user_id IS NULL DESC
```

The equivalent can be achieved with an ANSI standard `CASE` expression

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
     , t.lastname
     , t.category
     , t.keywords
     , t.text
     , CASE WHEN t.keywords LIKE '%text%' THEN
         CASE WHEN t.name     LIKE '%text%' THEN
           CASE WHEN t.text     LIKE '%text%' THEN
             CASE WHEN t.category LIKE '%text%' THEN
               4
             ELSE 3 END
           ELSE 2 END
         ELSE 1 END
       ELSE 0 END AS `points`
  FROM `users`
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT p.user_id FROM pages p GROUP BY p.user_id ) q
    ON q.user_id = t.id
HAVING `points` > 0
 ORDER
    BY `points` DESC, q.user_id IS NULL DESC
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

If the specification means that if the user supplied text occurs in any of the four columns, and the total number of "points" for each row is the number of columns in the row that had a match, then we can use simple addition of the conditional tests, rather than nesting them.

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
     , t.lastname
     , t.category
     , t.keywords
     , t.text
     , IF(t.keywords LIKE '%text%',1,0) +
       IF(t.name     LIKE '%text%',1,0) +
       IF(t.text     LIKE '%text%',1,0) +
       IF(t.category LIKE '%text%',1,0) AS `points`
  FROM `users` t
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT p.user_id FROM pages p GROUP BY p.user_id ) q
    ON q.user_id = t.id
HAVING `points` > 0 WHERE 
 ORDER BY `points` DESC, q.user_id IS NULL DESC
```

This query (like the prior queries) will list the users that had the highest calculated value for `points` first, then by whether or not there's a matching row found in the `pages` table. (The expression `q.user_id` will be NULL if there are no rows in `pages` that match on the `id` from `users`, and will be non-NULL if there was a match.  So ordering by the expression "`q.user_id IS NULL`" will sort the users with `pages` before users without `pages`.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the specification. I attributed meaning to the specific order the columns were to be searched for a match. And I attributed meaning to the specification "if it is **also** in". I took that to mean that we'd add 1 point if the previous check had succeeded, but otherwise, we wouldn't add a 1 point if the row hadn't previously matched. (The expression to derived `points` can easily be altered, if we want to add 1 to the point score for each match).

Comment: No, this is extra but not a solution what I need. Read again specification please. Scoring is a good addition but in the same order I must search database and user who has the most points AND with page to put in the first place and others to put below. Thanks!

Comment: There is no particular "order" which the database needs to be searched. A row either satisfies the predicates, and is returned, or it doesn't, and it's not returned. The `ORDER BY` clause specifies the sequence in which the rows are returned.